# If $E \subset \mathbb R$ is Lebesgue measurable, does there exist a closed set $F\subset E :\ m(E)=m(F)$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

My question is the following.

> If $E \subset \mathbb R$ is a Lebesgue measurable set, does there exist a closed set $F\subset E :\ m(E)=m(F)$?

$m$ stands for the Lebesgue measure of the real line.

I tried to prove this with the known approximation:

$$m(E)=\sup\{m(K):K\subset E,\ K\  \text{compact}\}$$

and I could only prove that there exists an $F \in F_{\sigma}:\ m(E)=m(F)$. The problem is that an $F_{\sigma}$ set is not necessarily a closed set.

Is the answer to my question affirmative? If it is, can you give me a hint for a proof?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** By a comment below we can check that when we do not have any restriction for $F$, the answer is trivial. What if we want $F\subset E$?

Comment: Presumably your question also needs $F \subseteq E$; otherwise the answer is trivially yes.

Comment: This question is also interesting if we relax the requirement by asking whether there exists a closed set $F$ such that $m(E\triangle F) = 0$, where $\triangle$ is the symmetric difference.

Comment: @SangchulLee I tried to prove this too. Since $m(E \triangle F)=0$ implies that $m(E)=m(F)$, we could have one more proof of the claim.

Comment: As in the answer below, the condition $F \subseteq E$ is so restrictive that the answer is negative. Asking $m(E\triangle F) = 0$ is slightly less restrictive as it give more room to play with, so answering this would be more nontrivial (and hopefully more interesting).

Comment: @SangchulLee, take any open superset $E$ of the rationals of measure 1. Now any closed set with measure 1 must have an open interval in its complement, which contains a piece of non-zero measure of $E$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A closed non-empty subset of the open unit interval $(0,1)$ would have to contain its own infimum, which would have to be $\epsilon > 0$. But then the measure of this closed subset is at most $1 - \epsilon < 1$.

Comment: @Mees de Vries Thanks for the answer, but how does this answer the general original question?

Comment: @SachpazisStelios, This does answer to your edited question .Without any restriction to $F$, as in your original question, you can simply choose $F$ to be a closed interval $[0, m(E)]$ (or $[0,\infty)$ when $m(E) = \infty$). This is probably the reason why Mees de Vries called it trivial.

Comment: @SangchulLee Ooh...thanks a lot Sangchul, I didn't think this. What if we want $F \subset E$?